# Errors while uploading apk in Amazon

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

While uploading my apk in Amazon, I am getting below permission errors.

```
android.hardware.location.gps
android.hardware.telephony
```

When I upload the same in Google play there is no issue. Can someone tell me how to deal with these errors, as I don't want to create multiple binaries for different devices

[image]

Comment: can you post the manifest to see the uses-permission?

Answer (score 0):

It clearly states that your APK uses permissions to things such as android.hardware.telephony which won't work some devices, try removing those devices if there is a list of devices you can choose from.